Source tables getting deselected in Data Stream
I have a Datastream enabled which replicates data from CloudSQL ( PostgreSQL ) to BigQuery. After the stream is created with automatic backfill, it runs for few hours and then the data replication gets stopped. I went to the source config and in the "Objects" tab, it seems my all the tables are deselected automatically. Also, there are no errors in the logs.
If I again manually select the required tables and initiate backfill, then it will run without any errors and the data will get refreshed in BiQuery.
What steps should I take in order that the tables don't get deselected and BigQuery gets populated with the latest data.
Checked the logs but didn't found out any error which is hampering the stream.
